# issue with URL redirection in Apache (mod_rewrite / mod_alias)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

There are many issues related to Apache configuration with mod_rewrite and mod_alias on Stack Exchange but I couldn't find an answer to my issue, so here is another question! ;)

I migrated an old website to a new location.

Articles used to be accessible to an URL such as `http://xxx/blog/index.php?post/YYYY/MM/DD/title`, so there are many links of that form through the existing webpages.

Now, the URL should be `http://xxx/post/YYYY/MM/DD/title`, so just remove `blog/index.php?` from the final URL.

I wanted to use mod_alias and a `Redirect` clause, but I read [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20131107001958/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/2007/09/12/apache-mod-rewrite) that the `Redirect` clause was interpreted after the `RewriteRule` clause, which is a problem in my case because I'm already using a `RewriteRule` condition.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

I tried to modify it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/index.php? / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

It almost works except:

1. `http://xxx/blog/index.php?post/YYYY/MM/DD/title` is redirected/rewritten to `http://xxx/blog/?post/YYYY/MM/DD/title` (note the `?`) so it doesn't work
2. it looks like this new line messes up a lot of other URLs that do not start with /blog/index.php? such as the backend URL...

Any help will be more than welcome!

### Edit (2014-07-16):

If I use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

then going to
`http://xxx/blog/index.php?test`
takes me to
`http://xxx/?test`
which is almost correct (the interrogation mark is still a problem)!

But when I try to match the interrogation mark by adding `\?`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/index\.php\?(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

then it just stops working... Going there:
`http://xxx/blog/index.php?test`
just leaves me there!

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule to the beginning of your set of rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?post/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /post/%1/%2/%3/%4? [L,R=301]
```

so that it looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?post/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /post/%1/%2/%3/%4? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: it almost works, but THE_REQUEST includes the whole HTTP line, which means my URLs end up like this: `http://xxx/post/YYYY/MM/DD/title%20HTTP/1.1`. I tried using two conditions instead, one using `REQUEST_URI` and the other using `QUERY_STRING` but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Pierre needed a `\ ` space in the brackets

Comment: Thanks! However, with complicated URLs (that include special characters and all), the rewriting has troubles. Please check my edited post, I found something easier to read, but I still can't make it work...

Comment: @Pierre Try adding a `NE` flag then to keep the redirected URL from getting encoded. You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. And matching against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` will just cause a rewrite loop.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried adding the `NE` flag but it doesn't change anything. If I try to access `http://xxx/blog/index.php?post/2011/01/01/This%2C-is-a-test`, it redirects me to `http://xxx/post/2011/01/01/This%25252C-is-a-test`, which does not exist.

Comment: @Pierre are you sure you're not looking at a cached version? [It works fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CDV4V.png)

Comment: You're right! After clearing the cache, it works fine! Thanks a lot!